# Json Serialisation Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, serialization

I am trying to serialise the json in the code below, the logs print out the display names successfully but I get a crash with an error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on the following lines:

> print(item["display-name"]! as!String)
>
> Blockquoteself.tableData.append(item["display-name"] as! String)

I can't seem to figure out why, any help much appreciated!

```html
  let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.asmserver.co.uk/sally/parsexml.php")!
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            
            
            
            if let urlContent = data {
                
                
                
                do {
                    
                    
                    
                    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: []) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                        
                        
                        
                            for item in jsonResult {
                            
                           
                           print(item["display-name"]! as!String)
                     
                            self.tableData.append(item["display-name"] as! String)
                            
                        
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                } catch {
                    
                    print("JSON serialization failed")
                    
                }
                
                
            } else {
                
                print("ERROR FOUND HERE")
            }
            
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                
            })
            
            self.tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            
            
        }
        
        task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that you really have a value before you use it and specially before using `as!`.

Do like this instead:

```
for item in jsonResult {
    guard let name = item["display-name"] as? String else { continue }
    print(name)
    self.tableData.append(name)
}
```

If the guard succeeds then you have a value and can use the `name` variable. You can also add several conditions to the `guard` statement.

Comment: brilliant thank you ! Ill mark answer once the time limit is up

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the guard statement, you could also use the similar `if let` construct:

```
if let item = item["display-name"] as? String {
    print(item)
} else {
    print("No display name")
}
```